# How to find the dominant color of an image with a palette of prespecified colors?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, colors, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to find the dominant color of an image such that the dominant color fits into some "region" of one of twelve pre-specified colors (red, orange, yellow, green, teal, blue, purple, pink, white, gray, black, brown). That is, I want to input an image and if, for example, the image is mainly yellow-green, then the program should output either yellow or green (depending on if it more green than yellow or more yellow than green).

It seems that most people use k-means clustering to find the dominant color, but (if I am correct) these k regions don't really seem to be pre-specified. That is the number k is specified, but if I input k = 12, I don't think that the algorithm will necessarily divide the regions according to my color list. Are there any other ways to do this?

I tried the following method (using PIL in Python): retrieve the histogram of the image and find the max values that correspond to the R, G, and B values (call them R1, G1, B1, respectively). Then find the color that is "closest" by finding the minimum Euclidean distance between the R1,G1,B1 and that of the R,G,B values from my palette list. This didn't seem to work so well because many of the colors retrieved were just gray and black, while the image itself didn't seem to have much gray nor much black in it, relative to the other colors.

This program is being coded in Python.

Is there another method to find the dominant color given a pre-specified palette?

Comment: It would help if you showed your palette, a couple of sample images, and what result you expect from each.

Comment: If you map each of the colours in your image to the closest one in your palette and then find the palette entry that occurs most often in the resulting image, that doesn't work because...?

Comment: Did you work it out ok?